# vim-latex: Environment mapping with arguments

Tags: environments, vim-latex

Is it possible to use `<F5>` to enclose in an environment with arguments? For instance, if I type `enumerate` and then `<F5>`, I get the following

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item <cursor>
\end{enumerate}<++>
```

Which is nice, but now how do I do to get the following

```
\begin{enumerate}[<cursor>]
    \item <++>
\end{enumerate}<++>
```

Is there a way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not really an answer to the questions asked, but I recommend using [snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets)

Comment: @Andrew Well that can fix the problem. I'll look at it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can redefine the environment mapping with the command

```
let g:Tex_Env_enumerate="\\begin{enumerate}[<++>]\<CR>\\item<++>\<CR>\\end{enumerate}<++>"
```

Or (which I think would be better) leave the enumerate mapping untouched and create a new mapping with a new name with otherwise the same command.

Comment: Your example is missing a `\\item` after the first `<CR>`. I would tend to redefine `g:Tex_Env_foo` with what I would find more useful although in this case it may be worth creating an alternative `g:Tex_Env_` as the default `enumerate` environment does not accept an optional argument.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing `\\item`, I added it. Regarding the `g:Tex_Env_foo`, isn't that what I already said?

Comment: I thought your answer was unclear as to why leaving the `enumerate` mapping untouched made sense.  There is nothing special about the default command or environment mappings of vim-LaTeX and they should generally be changed as the user sees fit, however as the `enumerate` environment of the LaTeX kernel does not accept an optional argument maintaining a mapping for `enumerate` which works without `enumitem` (or equivalent) along with one which does may be reasonable idea.  Alternatively just using `\\begin{enumerate}<++>\<CR>` may be more of a catch-all single mapping.